# Is it possible to change Windows 7 from Desktop Mode to Server Mode?

Tags: windows-7

I remember it may be possible to change Windows XP from "being a desktop mode" to more suited for being a server in a "server mode" -- probably more RAM allocated for hard disk caching, network resources, etc, instead of for GUI resource.

On Windows 7, is that possible, either through console or through control panel?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean the Perfomance Options where you can choose between Adjust Best Performance for Programs or Background Services? They're still there, in the same place. Right click the Computer icon, Properties, Advanced System Settings, Advanced, select the Performance Settings, open Advanced tab

Comment: not sure if they are the same... server is more server related... background services can be anything... weather checking... CPU meter...

Comment: According to the context help, this merely switches the scheduler between prioritizing the foreground program ("Programs") and giving equal CPU share to foreground and background ("Background services"). **However,** the system cache option is in the same place, labelled *Memory usage*, and this seems like what @Jian was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a guide on optimizing Windows 7 for performance including disabling visual effects, disabling startup programs, and defragmenting your hard drive http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/Optimize-Windows-7-for-better-performance”>here on Microsoft.com. You can also find articles on monitoring and maintaining system performance http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/aa905090.aspx”>here at the Springboard site on TechNet.

Brandon
Windows Outreach Team- IT Pro

Comment: oh if you know the link some time could you list it here... (or the link to that particular page out of the whole guide)